# Cannot run docker container with non root user for mariadb image

Tags: mysql, docker, mariadb, dockerfile

Without a non root user the docker container that is running out of the dockerfile is working without error but when I add a user then I am getting following error:

```
    Initializing database 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [Warning] Can't create test file /var/lib/mysql/9e79cb48a1f0.lower-test 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied") 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] mysqld: Got error 'Can't create file' when trying to use aria control file '/var/lib/mysql/aria_log_control' 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' init function returned error. 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] Plugin 'Aria' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed. 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation. 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory. 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Operating system error number 13 in a file operation. 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: The error means mysqld does not have the access rights to the directory. 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot open datafile './ibdata1' 2019-07-17 21:28:05 0
 [ERROR] InnoDB: Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit innodb_data_file_path in my.cnf back to what it was, and remove the new ibdata files InnoDB created in this failed attempt. InnoDB only wrote those files full of zeros, but did not yet use them in any way. But be careful: do not remove old data files which contain your precious data!
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM mariadb:10.3.5

RUN apt-get update & apt-get upgrade -y

ENV MYSQL_USER=user1 \
    MYSQL_PASSWORD=pass5 \
    MYSQL_DATABASE=db \
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=XXX



RUN useradd -ms /bin/bash newuser
USER newuser
WORKDIR /home/newuser
RUN sudo chown -R newuser:newuser /var/lib/mysql
ADD . /home/newuser

I would like to see the container to run as non root user
```

Comment: OS "root" or MariaDB "root"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look into the content of Dockerfile, They already adding one no-root user in the [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/master/10.3/Dockerfile), then why you need the other one?

```
# add our user and group first to make sure their IDs get assigned consistently, regardless of whatever dependencies get added
RUN groupadd -r mysql && useradd -r -g mysql mysql
```

your this step also ignored,

```
RUN sudo chown -R newuser:newuser /var/lib/mysql
```

[image]

But it fails when it comes to the offical docker [entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/master/10.3/docker-entrypoint.sh), they run DB initialization or other stuff as a MySQL user so the new user will not permit for the following file so defiantly it will throw permission denied.

[image]

If you really want to do this you have to override docker-entry point or might be some part of dockerfile.
Here is code form offical [Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/mariadb/blob/master/10.3/Dockerfile)

```
rm -rf /var/lib/mysql; \
        mkdir -p /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld; \
        chown -R mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/run/mysqld; \
    # ensure that /var/run/mysqld (used for socket and lock files) is writable regardless of the UID our mysqld instance ends up having at runtime
        chmod 777 /var/run/mysqld; \
```

Comment: I added USER mysql in my dockerfile and it started with the non root user mysql. THank you Adii.

Comment: Glad to know 